# Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi"), but fi is already there

Tags: bash

When ever I try to run this bash it gives me a syntax error that the end is unexpected and it expects a "fi" on the last line and it is already there.  I am still fairly new to bash but I know enough to do basic stuff.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "============================================================================================"
echo "||What is the Songs Genre (Classical, Country, Disco, Dubstep, Pop, Rap, Rock, or Techno)?||"
echo "============================================================================================"

read "Genre"

if ( $genre=="Classical")
then 
cd ~/Music/Classical

if ( $genre=="Country") 
then
cd ~/Music/Country

if ( $genre=="Disco") 
then
cd ~/Music/Disco

if ( $genre=="Dubstep")
then 
cd ~/Music/Dubstep

if ( $genre=="Pop") 
then
cd ~/Music/Pop

if ( $genre=="Rap")
then 
cd ~/Music/Rap

if ( $genre=="Rock")
then 
cd ~/Music/Rock

if ( $genre=="Techno")
then 
cd ~/Music/Techno

fi

echo "============================"
echo "||Paste Youtube link here.||"
echo "============================"

read "Link"
sudo youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 $Link

echo "========================"
echo "||Any More songs?(Y/N)||"
echo "========================"

read "Loop"

if $Loop==Y
then
cd
sh youtube.sh & exit

else
exit
fi
```

Comment: Did you think you could get away without putting it for the others?

Comment: I believe you want to use `elif` for all but the first if that isn't closed

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend. Run your code through, fix what it finds, and **then** come back here. (`( $genre=="Pop")` isn't a valid comparison at all, for instance).

Comment: All those `if` statements should probably be a `case` statement.

Comment: you need one `fi` per `if`...   you have a lot of if's that are never closed.

Comment: Please just google `bash if then else` before you post here

Answer (score 1):

You either need to put `fi` after each `if...then` block, or change your `if` statements after the first one to `elif`.

Comment: Necessary, but not *sufficient* to actually get the OP's code working. `if ( $genre=="Techno")` will never do what the OP expects it to, for example. (This is part of why [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) specifies that one should "Answer Well-Asked Questions"; if the question were scoped to a single problem rather than posting a script with a whole bunch of problems, this would be less of a issue).

Comment: The question specifically asks about a syntax error. I answered that syntax question. If there are other errors with the code so be it, but the question was very direct in what it was asking, making it a Well-Asked Question. If the question was what is wrong with this code, then I'd agree with you, but it is not.

Comment: It's not well-asked if it includes a whole script (with a bunch of other bugs) instead of a [mcve] with the shortest code necessary to allow others to reproduce only on the syntax error at hand.

Comment: If they knew how to produce that here then wouldn't they have had to know how to fix their syntax error?

Comment: You don't need to know the immediate cause of a problem a priori to iteratively take things out until it goes away and then back up a step. Both the Help Center MCVE page (to which I previously linked) and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) discuss the methodology. (And indeed, following that process often *will* result in a question not needing to be asked at all).

Answer (score 1):

That can be a lot more concise. I'd write this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "=============================================="

# put the genre names into an array 
genres=( Classical Country Disco Dubstep Pop Rap Rock Techno )

# use `select` instead of a cascading if statement
PS3="Select a genre: "
select choice in "${genres[@]}"; do
    # a tricky condition to check if the choice is in the array
    if [[ " ${genres[*]} " == *" $choice "* ]]; then
        break
    fi
done

read -p "Enter Youtube link: " link

mkdir -p ~/Music/"$choice"       # ensure the directory exists
cd ~/Music/"$choice"
youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 "$link"    # do you really need sudo for this?

read -p "Again?(Y/N) " again
if [[ $again == [yY]* ]]; then
    exec "$0"                    # re-launch without hardcoding the program name
fi
```